# Editing av_spectrogram_video R

Tags: r, spectrogram, code

I'm trying out producing some spectrogram videos in R for presentations and sharing through av_spectrogram_video (from the av package), but would like to crop the spectrogram to zoom in on lower frequencies, this doesn't seem to be an option in the plotting function - does anyone know a better way to do this or another package?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit late, but here is a function from another package that might do what you want:

```
install.packages("dynaSpec")
?dynaSpec::scrolling_spectro()
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not language specific but I suggest to first decimate the audio data to a sampling frequency that is twice the desired visible frequency before using the av_spectrogram_video.